# Travelling with Vyvanse to India and Dubai from Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, legal, health

I require urgent help in regards to carrying ADHD medication and mood stabilisers to India and Dubai. My doctor suggested I don’t need documentation as my medication bottles list the dosage and my legal name.

However, I’ve been getting mixed responses from the internet on what’s legal.

I take the following medications and it’s vital that I do not stop taking them.

- 50mg Vyvanse
- 50mg Lamotrigine
- 50mg Seroquel

I’m unsure what to do and whom to contact. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162592/need-advice-on-traveling-with-venlafaxine-and-vyvanse-to-india) should help

Comment: Tell the doctor that you NEED that documentation, for your anxiety related issues. That should be enough for them to supply it, even if the bottles would be enough. (I do not know whether they are or not.)

Comment: Pretty much every travel advice site I’ve ever seen states that travelling with the actual prescription is at least strongly recommended and in some cases essential. I would expect a reputable medical practitioner to be amenable to what is a very common situation (and it would arouse my suspicions if they were in any way reluctant to supply one). For Dubai, see eg https://www.uae-embassy.org/permitted-prescriptionsdrugs-while-entering-uae

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traveling with Venlafaxine and Vyvanse to India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162592/traveling-with-venlafaxine-and-vyvanse-to-india)

Comment: @mdewey The question is fairly closely related to this one, but doesn't address the Dubai/UAE part of it.

Comment: @mlc I had not read it carefully enough. I have retracted my close vote but left the comment. Many thanks for the correction.